# color hex number

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, hex

I will start by telling you that I am quite new with Photoshop and I would be grateful if someone could help me. 
I've made a logo and one of the colours I used, would like to use again and I cannot find the hex number. I mean, I know is brown, but what kind of brown? Is there any way for me to find out more information - including the colour - of a particular element?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the eyedropper tool, click inside your "brown" area. You'll see it pop up on the fill color (bottom of the tool palette). Double-click on the swatch and it will bring up the color info - the hex, hsv, etc. values are all there.

Comment: thank you so much ...it seems so easy when you know the answer :D ...wish you a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the hex number:
1. Use the colour picker to choose your color
2. double click the color
3. there's the hex number[image]

Comment: thank you so much ...your answer was very helpful too, but apparently I cannot consider only one as being the best...too bad, cause both answers were very good ...wish you a nice day :)